# Multiple DialogFragment restored after Activity gets killed

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-dialogfragment

I have  **1 Activity showing 1 DialogFragment** and I use setAlwaysFinish app to force the Activity to get killed after onPause.

After pausing & restoring the Activity, I **sometimes** got **2** or **3** of the same DialogFragment shown. Does anybody know how to prevent this?

**Note: I left the Activity with the Dialog still showing. The bug's revealed after several trying with setAlwaysFinish.**

Code: Activity

```
package com.example.testdialog;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void showDialog(View v) {
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        DialogFragment d = DateDialog.newInstance(today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), today.get(Calendar.MONTH), today.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        d.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "mydialog");
    }
}
```

Code: DialogFragment

```
package com.example.testdialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

public class DateDialog extends DialogFragment implements OnDateSetListener {
    public static final String TAG = "datepicker";
    public static final int SEARCH_FLIGHT = 0;
    public static final int PASSENGER = 1;

    static DateDialog newInstance(int day, int month, int year) {
        DateDialog d = new DateDialog();
        Bundle bun = new Bundle();
        bun.putInt("day", day);
        bun.putInt("month", month);
        bun.putInt("year", year);
        d.setArguments(bun);
        return d;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle bun = getArguments();
        int year = bun.getInt("year");
        int month = bun.getInt("month");
        int day = bun.getInt("day");

        DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        d.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", d);
        d.setTitle("my dialog");
        return d;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        Dialog d = getDialog();
        if (d != null && getRetainInstance())
            d.setDismissMessage(null);
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide your code ??

Comment: it's really standard code, i've updated my question

Answer (score 4):

You can prefent it by using this in your dialogfragment:

```
@Override
public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
    if (tag != null && tag.equals("FRAGMENT_TAG_MAX_ONE_INSTANCE")) {
        // we do not show it twice
        if (manager.findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) {
            super.show(manager, tag);
        }
    } else {
        super.show(manager, tag);
    }
}
```

and changing:

```
d.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "FRAGMENT_TAG_MAX_ONE_INSTANCE");
```

Comment: Thanks, it really helped

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue and dont know real way to solve it but this way can help you

```
private void showLostPassDialog() {
    if (!dialogShown) {
        dialogShown = true;
        DialogFragment newFragment = new LostPassDialogFragment();
        newFragment.setCancelable(false);
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }
}
```

and when destroy dialog set `dialogShown=false` as i did :

```
public static class LostPassDialogFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment {
    ....
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dialogShown = false;
        super.onDestroy();

    }
```

hope to b e useful

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you close the dialog, close it properly by calling

```
    dialog.dismiss();
    dialog.cancel();
```

Comment: i didn't close the dialog. I left the Activity with the dialog still showing.

Comment: Ok, then add these settings to your activity in the manifest file  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
android:launchMode="singleTask"

Answer (score 0):

For me this same problem occurred when I used`getDialog().setOnDismissListener()` inside `DialogFragment`.

After going through `DialogFragment`'s documentation I found this:

> Note: DialogFragment own the Dialog.setOnCancelListener and
>   Dialog.setOnDismissListener callbacks. You must not set them yourself.
>   To find out about these events, override onCancel(DialogInterface) and
>   onDismiss(DialogInterface) Source: [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html#oncreatedialog)

Removing `getDialog().setOnDismissListener()` and implementing `onDismiss(DialogInterface)` fixed this.